# Datatables.js - multiple customized languages

Tags: jquery, datatables-1.10

I'm working with Datatables.js in different human languages. I'm using the language plugins provided by Datatables and they work fine. However, I would like to overwrite a few of the translations with my own translations.

How can I do this in the best way?

Here's my code:

```
  function getLanguage() {
    var $langMap = {
      en: 'English',
      es: 'Spanish'
    };
    var $lang = $('html').attr('lang');
    return '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.13/i18n/' + $langMap[$lang] + '.json';
  }

  // Build Datatable
  $('#example').DataTable({
    language: {
      url: getLanguage() // works perfectly, but I need to overwrite with a few custom text options
    }
  });
```

Say, I want to owerwrite these language options:

```
  en: {
    // Overwrite defaults with this string
    "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page - custom test",
  },
  es: {
    // Overwrite Spanish defaults with this string
    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros - algo muy especial...",
  }
```

[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/4ebzccwb/3/).

Ref: [Datatables.js language options](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/language.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could expand your `langMap` to hold the modifications you want to add to the language struct :

```js
var langMap = {
  en: {
    path: 'English',
    mods: {
      sLengthMenu: "Display _MENU_ records per page - custom test"
    }
  },
  es: {
    path: 'Spanish',
    mods: {
      sLengthMenu: "Mostrar _MENU_ registros - algo muy especial..."
    }
  }
};
```

Notice I am using hungarian notation, `sLengthMenu` instead of `lengthMenu`. This is due to the fact that the language files still is using this format. Then load the language object through a synchronous AJAX request, modify with the `mods` and return

```js
function getLanguage() {
  var lang = $('html').attr('lang');
  var path = '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.13/i18n/';
  var result = null;
  $.ajax({
    async: false,  
    url: path + langMap[lang].path + '.json',
    success: function(obj) {
      result = $.extend({}, obj, langMap[lang].mods)
    }
  })
  return result
}

// Build Datatable
$('#example').DataTable({
  language: getLanguage() 
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/v84wjLqe/** (with hardcoded `es` just for test)

Note: Instead of using `async: false` you could consider using a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), jQuery [deferred](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/), [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) or one of the promise polyfills. But this is beyond the question.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Awesome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: davidkonrad > how can I create a fallback - say, if the page has `html lang="fi"` and `fi` is not defined in the `langMap` - how can I create a fallback to English?

Comment: `var lang = $('html').attr('lang'); if (!langMap[lang]) lang = 'en';` ...? Could be nicer.